# Set autoplay on jQuery Tabs Slideshow

Tags: jquery, slideshow, autoplay

I've just installed the jQuery Tabs slideshow plugin and would like it to autoplay. However, when I put in the autoplay option, it performs very unevenly, not at all like when the play button is pressed manually.

```
<script language="JavaScript">

$(function() {

$(".slidetabs").tabs(".images > div", {

// enable "cross-fading" effect
effect: 'fade',
fadeOutSpeed: "slow",

// start from the beginning after the last tab
rotate: true

// use the slideshow plugin. It accepts its own configuration
}).slideshow({autoplay:true});
});
</script>
```

Have I put the autoplay code in correctly? Here is the documentation. http://flowplayer.org/tools/tabs/slideshow.html Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how mine looked

```
$(document).ready(function () {  //this is jQuery's "on Load" event
        $("#featured > ul").tabs({ fx: { opacity: 'toggle'} }).tabs("rotate", 5000, true);
    });
```